# React : Update dropzone

Tags: reactjs, dropzone.js

I develop in react.js and i'm using dropzone.
How can i update dropzone component to have upload zone, and not "remove file" ?
It work if I update the page, but I don't want to update the page .. 
Thank you

Comment: You question lack alot of information, you should consider adding some code of your tries and maybe a little bit more about what you are trying to acheive. Please note that we are not a coding service, we won't code this for you. Submit what you tried and we will help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Salut. Pourrez-vous écrire un commentaire, en français, pour que je peux peut-être t'aider à améliorer ta question ?